# AndroidManifest.xml file doesn't exist in default MAUI project

Tags: c#, android, android-manifest, maui

I have created the MAUI project according to the getting started guide:

- [Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation)
- [Build your first app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app)

It is a default project without any changes.
Now, I am trying to build my project and I get the next errors:

- `Specified AndroidManifest file does not exist: C:\***\source\repos\MauiApp\MauiApp\AndroidManifest.xml.`
- `Assets file 'C:\***\source\repos\MauiApp\MauiApp\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.`

I have tried to restore NuGet but it doesn't help. What did I miss? or any suggestion for fixing?

**EDIT:**

- Windows 10 Pro,19043.1237
- Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview, 17.0.0 Preview 5.0

Comment: Which OS are you using? I had the same problem on macOS, but worked fine on windows. Also, does the file exist?

Comment: which visual studio 2022 preview version are you using. I recently downloaded Visual Studio preview 5. Not faced any problem. Can you try latest preview version .

Comment: hi guys, I have added OS version and I am using latest version of VS 2022

Comment: I have it in VStud 17.4 OSX pre-existing project ... new Maui projects work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This issue was fixed in the Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview, 17.0.0 Preview **6.0**

Comment: I have this issue in 17.1.0 Preview 1

Comment: I have it in VStud 17.4 OSX pre-existing ... new Maui projects work.

Comment: I have in VS2022 17.8.0

Comment: Still not working in 17.8.1! Very strange behavior - worked the whole day without issues (dev-compile-debug on Android emulator and physical device), all of a sudden, this error popped out.

Comment: This happened to me on 17.8.3 .net 8

Comment: Happened to me on VS 17.8.5 .NET8. Palo's solution worked for me. Scary.

Comment: Just happened in VS 17.8.4.

Comment: And in 17.9 too.

Answer (score 14):

I have this solved, ...well, kind of. Let me explain: I have got a solution with 18 projects, three of them are MAUI projects targeting just `net8.0-android`. All three projects suddenly started to produce the `XA1018` error:

```
XA1018  Specified AndroidManifest file does not exist: <MauiProjectFolder>\AndroidManifest.xml.
```

In addition, the projects also produce the `NU1008` error:

```
NU1008: Projects that use central package version management should not define the version on the PackageReference items but on the PackageVersion items...
```

Although the central package version management is setup correctly (it already worked as stated in my previous comment).

What solved the issue for me (at least temporarily) was the following:

1. Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` file from the `Platforms/Android` subfolder into the project's root folder for each affected MAUI project.
2. Rebuild solution - should be rebuilt successfully.
3. Now you can remove the `AndroidManifest.xml` files form the MAUI project's root folder and VS (or MSBuild, I do not know which one) does not complain anymore.

**This is insane!**

Comment: The accepted answer should be updated to this. I'm sure at the time that was the case, however, Google took me here where your answer solved the issue.

Comment: Reference Issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21406

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be related to central package management (CPM).

[Using central package management causes build breaking NU1009 with MAUI projects · Issue #12953 · dotnet/maui](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12953)

I had the same problem when adding a new MAUI project to our existing repo, which has `Directory.Packages.props` (CPM), `Directory.Build.props` with common config and `global.json` to select .NET SDK version.

When adding a new MAUI project outside our repo without all these common files, I had no problems. I have not eliminated exactly which file or config caused problems yet, will post an update then.

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the same problem with Visual Studio 2022, version 17.9.3

I solved this way:

- right click on Project Dependencies ==> Manage NuGet Reference
- for "Microsoft.Maui.Controls" and "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" the version in use was 8.0.7 and an upgrade to 8.0.10 was available

once upgraded the two packages the project could compile without problem and the application started.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command in **Developer PowerShell** pane within VS2022 fixed the problem for me:

```
msbuild /target:Restore <YourSolution.sln>
```

This command restored NuGet packages needed by MAUI project. After this command completed (and 15-20 seconds passed), a dialog appeared asking for Android SDK installation. Afterwards, rebuilding the project gave me the sweet `Rebuild succeeded` message.

I'm in VS2022 (17.9.0) and targeting .NET 8.

Answer (score 0):

Restore Nuget Package and Rebuild.